# Is there a way to install and run a local server on my Windows XP Home laptop?

Tags: iis, windows-xp

I'm looking to set up a local server on my laptop which is running Windows XP Home Edition. I've noticed that it is impossible to install IIS on the Home Edition, but is there a way around this? Is there other software that I can install to run a server?

the purpose behind this is to mess around and play with ASP to create dynamic websites and my only computer I own has Home Edition.

Also, would running a server on my 5 year old laptop with 2GB of RAM be a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP Home Edition does not come with IIS (only Professional). There are workarounds available, but Home Edition was not designed for this. Visual Studio (full and express) come with Cassini, which is a version of IIS you can use for testing/development.

What is your desired result?

Comment: I just want to develop my own website projects that can connect with databases and such. Haven't done much in the realm of dynamic websites yet.

Comment: Visual Studio Express should be all you need to get started. You may even want to check out a MS product called WebMatrix; it can really expedite the time from idea -> working product, and easy deployment to shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You can always install [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/). It should work fine on your HW.

Comment: Apache... interesting!

HW? I haven't had homework in over four years!

Comment: Not entirely sure why you'd go with Apache for ASP.net websites, but it IS doable.

Comment: Main reasons is that it is portable and has quite low HW requirements.

Comment: Hah, I'm just not with it today.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use: http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/

The X1 version is totally free and works great. You can then add PHP as needed (or not)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are ways like http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020118.htm
If you are developing using Visual Studio 2005, 8 , 10 you don't need IIS.

The hardware should be fine as you will be the only user accessing the website :)

Comment: What if I wanted another computer in my home to connect to the website. Is that possible? And how easy would it be?

Comment: You mean brows the website? or access a webservice. Both are possible but you will have to run the site from VS before you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Download Ultidev Cassini and be happy...Ez to configure and use in both localhost and local network.